# API patch request getting 200 in postman but 404 with supertest

Tags: rest, api, request, postman, supertest

I am getting started on an API testing project using supertest, mocha and chai. I am using postman to manually send the requests first to ensure they are working before writing the code for them.

All my get and post commands are working successfully except for this patch request. This is the first `patch` request I am attempting to send.

**Request Headers**
[image: postman]

**Request Body**

[image: body of postman request]

**Code**
[image: code]

- First request is passing, second is failing
- The URL's are identical so I know they are valid and the authorization is working correctly.
- I feel that as the first command is passing this is not a sync issue
- This definitely needs to be a patch request according to the swagger

I'm new to API testing so would greatly appreciate any insight anyone may have into this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Well nobody ever likes to hear it but it appears my problem has resolved itself after leaving it for a day.

I really wish I had an understanding of why this has happened but for now it appears I will have to go ahead unsure of what caused it or how it was resolved.